# ParseResults getName() return None

Tags: python, text-processing, pyparsing

I am using pyparsing version 2.4.0. getName() return None from the given ParseResults.

Please find below as the code snippet. Any insights is highly appreciated.

```
import pyparsing as pp

def abc1():
    grammar = pp.Literal('something1') + pp.Suppress('=') + pp.pyparsing_common.number
    return grammar

def abc2():
    grammar = pp.Literal('something2') + pp.Suppress('=') + pp.pyparsing_common.number
    return grammar

grammar = pp.Group(abc1())('abc1*') | pp.Group(abc2())('abc2*')
parser = pp.ZeroOrMore(grammar)
data = parser.parseFile(<file>, True)

for res in data:
    print(res.getName())  # Expect to print value of "abc1" and "abc2".
```

Comment: This code sample is incomplete.  You haven't defined `pp` or `abc()`.  Please post a complete program that we can run ourselves.

Comment: [mcve] please - you are not even calling `getName()` nor are you providing any data to it which might be kinda crucial

Comment: Sorry, my bad for incomplete code snippet. It is updated now.

Comment: Instead of using parseFile (which reads from an external file, which is problematic when posting on SO), could you please include the text you are parsing as a string variable, and then use `parser.parseString()`?

Comment: When I run your code with pyparsing 2.4.0 and pass it this text "something1=100 something2=42", I get your desired output.

Comment: @PaulMcG Thanks for helping out. It works after fixing up the virtual env setup. I used PyPy to improve overall parsing runtime.